# In OpenGL ES 2.0, how can I draw a wireframe of triangles except for the lines on adjacent coplanar faces?

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, edges, wireframe

I vaguely remember seeing something in OpenGL (not ES, which was still at v1.0 on the iPhone when I came across this, which is why I never used it) that let me specify which edges of my polygons were considered outlines vs those that made up the interior of faces.  As such, this isn't the same as the outline of the entire model (which I know how to do), but rather the outline of a planar face with all its tris basically blended into one poly.  For instance, in a cube made up of tri's, each face is actually two tris.  I want to render the outline of the square, but not the diagonal across the face.  Same thing with a hexagon.  That takes four tris, but just one outline for the face.

Now yes, I know I can simply test all the edges to see if they share coplanar faces, but I could have sworn I remember seeing somewhere when you're defining the tri mesh data where you could say 'this line outlines a face whereas this one is inside a face.' That way when rendering, you could set a flag that basically says 'Give me a wireframe, but only the wires around the edges of complete faces, not around the tris that make them up.'

BTW, my target is all platforms that support OpenGL ES 2.0 but my dev platform is iOS.  Again, this Im pretty sure was originally in OpenGL and may have been depreciated once shaders came on the scene, but I can't even find a reference to this feature to check if that's the case.

The only way I know now is to have one set of vertices, but two separate sets of indices... one for rendering tris, and another for rendering the wireframes of the faces.  It's a real pain since I end up hand-coding a lot of this, which again, I'm 99% sure you can define when rendering the lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GL_QUADS, glEdgeFlag and glPolygonMode are not supported in OpenGL ES.

You could use LINES to draw the wireframe: To get hidden lines, first draw black filled triangles (with DEPTH on) and then draw the edges you are interested in with GL_LINES.

Comment: Nope!  ES 2.0 doesn't support quads.  Plus, that would only work for a square.  I need this to work for any defined face with coplanar tris.  Again, I know I remember seeing it for OpenGL because I was really bummed that it wasn't in ES 1.0.  I'm hoping they added something in ES 2.0 for it.  (Then again, maybe it was part of OpenGL that was depreciated once shaders and such came around.  Problem is I can't even find the original thing to be able to check!)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that QUADS are not there. http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/es_cm_spec_2.0.24.pdf on page 4 says: "The QUADS, QUAD STRIP, and POLYGON primitives are not supported." However, LINES are still supported. You could use those.

Comment: I know I can use lines... that's not the issue.  The issue is a tri is made up of three lines.  However, in the case of a square, each of the two triangles only have two lines that are on the edge of the face.  The third, the diagonal hypotenuse is on the face itself.  There's a way when rendering lines to say that's an interior-face line that you can choose to render or not, without having to go back and define a second set of indices that only specify the outer edges.  That's what I'm trying to find again, and getting nowhere fast.

Comment: In other words... I can define the set of lines once, and simply set a flag to say to render all triangle edges, or just the edges around a face.  Forgive me for being redundant here, but I want to make sure everyone understands what I'm trying to find.  Again, this was a feature of OpenGL.  Just can't remember what it was.

Comment: I believe I found the answer on the same page of the ES spec: "Edge ﬂags are not included, as they are only used when drawing
polygons as outlines and support for PolygonMode has not been included. [...] Elimination of quads and polygons removes special cases for line mode drawing
requiring edge ﬂags (should PolygonMode be re-instated)". I think the function you couldn't remember is glEdgeFlag.

Comment: Ooops!  You were right.  I see that in your answer (unless you edited it!)  It was glEdgeFlag and that doesn't work with arrays, only direct mode which isn't supported by ES, hence glEdgeFlag isn't supported by ES either.  Guess it's manually specifying two different arrays... one for the faces, one for the edges.  Still, I'm marking yours as the answer for at least finding it.

Comment: Not oops! I just learned these things during our discussion. Then I edited my answer so that other people don't have to parse through all these comments.